# Custom images as markers when using GMUClusters

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Can we add custom images as markers on Google maps when the markers are generated using `GMUClusterManager`? i.e. The markers are added automatically on the map when we tap on clusters and in place of those default markers I want my custom images. Is it possible?

If so, how can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

This might help, this is a perfect example of GMUClusterManager

http://studyswift.blogspot.in/2016/07/marker-clustering-with-googles-utility.html